# jquery .attr() returning undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a form element:

```
<form name="editTourneyForm" data-tourney-id="28">
```

and a jquery selector:

```
$('#editTourneyForm').attr('data-tourney-id')
```

When I try to access either attribute (data or name) via `.attr()` it returns undefined. When I inspect the jQuery object I can't find either attribute anywhere (granted I am not farmiliar with the jQuery object structure) although both the attr and data properties have `length=2`. I have no idea what might be going wrong. The form is not generated at runtime so it shouldn't be an issue of dynamic content not being selected.

I had already had it working before and I made some changes to other parts of my project and now this is broken somehow, any ideas?

Comment: `#thing` <= is an id selector.  You do not have an id on that element.

Comment: `$('form[name="editTourneyForm"]')` <= would be a tagName & attribute selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you don't have any id for the element. It just has the `name` attribute on the basis of which you are trying to select.

Use the below selector to do so :

```
$('form[name=editTourneyForm]')
```

Besides that, although the attribute you are trying to access can be accessed using `.attr()`, but data-attributes are recommended to be accessed using `.data()`. Do that like this :

```
$('form[name=editTourneyForm]').data('tourney-id');
```

Comment: Oh wow, thats a big goof. Im like 99% sure this was one of the changes I said I made to (what I thought was) other parts of my code, definitely had both name and id before, got rid of the id to simplify things not realizing Im using it. Welp, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a JQuery data() method. Use `$('form[name="editTourneyForm"]').data('tourney-id')` instead. Please check their [doc](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Make sure to use correct selector.